# Magento getting error on product flat data reindixing

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

Getting this error

while reindexing using ssh command

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table './admin_magento16/catalog_product_flat_4.frm' (errno: 150)' in /home/magesite/public_html/store/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

in my magento database there is no catalog_product_flat_4 table is present

what should I need to do for this?

Comment: Can you confirm that there is enough disk space and that the db user has `CREATE TABLE` privileges?

Comment: @benmarks yes the space and privileges are fine

Comment: All signs point to foreign key issue. Refer to the following post and try to reindex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5667983/833795 - particularly regarding the `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command. Also, you might consider committing to [the proposal for a dedicated StackExchane Magento site (link)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48872/magento?referrer=HFqQT3Qeb2X27y6ehRWkiw2) where questions such as this would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

able to solve this problem with our team

1st I checked database

checked the core_store table there are 4 store created

also the catalog_product_flat_2 , 3 , 4 tables are missed

I checked my admin panel there is only 1 store

so create the sites from admin panel add added the catalog_product_flat_2 , 3 , 4
then re-index is works fine

cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you clean Magento cache before reindexing?
I can recommend you to check your database with original [Magento Database Repair Tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool)